# Resolved: How to update KDB+/q non commercial version?

Tags: kdb

I can't seem to get KDB+/q to update.

I've been googling the issue, searched Kx Systems' website, and I've tried just downloading the files again and replacing the ones I have, but when I'm starting up q it still says KDB+ 4.0 rather than 4.1. What am I missing? How hard can it be to update q?

Comment: This might be a question for [dba.se]

Comment: Is QHOME set pointing to the old install? Is "q" an alias pointing to an old install?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers guys! I found out that there was an updated version of KDB at https://portal.dl.kx.com/assets/raw/kdb+/ . I downloaded l64 and replaced the files in my installation manually.